# Using addlister in MATLAB GUI seems to "delete" existing handles

Tags: matlab, slider, listener, matlab-guide

I am quite new to MATLAB GUI programming (using GUIDE sorry) and I have the following issue: The GUI displays on an axis an image sequence stored in a cell array. I have a couple of pushbuttons and a slider to scroll through the sequence. In order to get a 'continuous slider' I use a listener, which kind of works but creates some problems:

1) When I press the slider, a figure is created and the first frame of the sequence is displayed in it, but as I move the slider the sequence is displayed in the axis of my GUI (which is what I want) and the figure becomes empty.  Can anybody tell me why this figure is created and how can I avoid it?

2) Once I press the slider button and thus use the listener, all handles inside the GUI are not functionnal as Matlab does not recognize them and I'm stuck with a functionnal slider/display but I can't use the pushbuttons.

Any ideas on why this happens? Here is the code I use in the Create Function of the slider:

```
function slider2_Frame_Video_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

hListener = addlistener(hObject,'ContinuousValueChange',@(a,b) slider2_Frame_Video_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)); % a and b are dummy arguments

guidata(hObject,handles)
```

In the slider callback, the code looks like this (basically imshow in the current axis):

```
axes(hAxis)
imshow(Movie{frame},'parent',hAxis);
```

`drawnow`

% This does not work either as handles.edit_FrameNumber is not recognized by Matlab

```
set(handles.edit_FrameNumber, 'String', frame);

guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Any hints are welcome thanks!

Comment: Alright thanks Geoff you're right! Also if I use an external function to continuously display the current frame (instead of within the slider callback) it seems to work. The "Movie" cell array is stored in a structure containing all the global variables which I share between callbacks using setappdata/getappdata; it prevents me from declaring variables as 'global' at the beginning of each callback. Also if it can be of any help to someone reading this the figure that appeared outside the GUI when I used the listener was due to my calling 'gca' just before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if part of the problem is that a listener is being instantiated each time the user moves the slider since the listener code is within this callback AND that the callback being provided to the listener (seems like some kind of strange back-and-forth there).  So every time the user releases the mouse button after a slide, a new listener is created.  This may be causing some problems with the other buttons not being responsive.

Rather than instantiating the listener there, I would do this in the `Opening_Fcn` of your GUI:

```
% --- Executes just before frameSlider is made visible.
function frameSlider_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to frameSlider (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for frameSlider
handles.output = hObject;

if ~isfield(handles,'hListener')
    handles.hListener = ...
        addlistener(handles.slider1,'ContinuousValueChange',@respondToContSlideCallback);
end

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

My GUI is named `frameSlider`; yours will be something else.  The above creates one listener with a callback to a function that you will need to define in the same *.m file, `respondToContSlideCallback`.

A sample body for the callback that is to respond to the continuous slide is

```
% --- Executes on slider movement.
function respondToContSlideCallback(hObject, eventdata)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider

% first we need the handles structure which we can get from hObject
handles = guidata(hObject);

% test to display the current value along the slider
disp(['at slider coordinate ' num2str(get(hObject,'Value'))]);
```

If you run this code, the Command Window will display continuously the slider coordinate as you move the slider from end to end.

Your above code has a `Movies` cell array.  How is that being accessed by your callback?  Is it a global variable or ..?  Where does `hist` come from?  If `Movies` is the result of some other function call, then it can be saved to `handles` too (in whichever location it gets loaded from file).  I suppose you will also have to map the slider control coordinates to the number of frames that you have (though maybe you have already done this?).